# How to create new log file for each run of tests in pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pytest, python-logging

I have created a `pytest.ini` file,

```
addopts = --resultlog=log.txt
```

This creates a log file, but I would like to create a new log file everytime I run the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question.
As hoefling mentioned `--result-log` is deprecated, I had to find a way to do it without using that flag. Here's how I did it,

conftest.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def pytest_assertrepr_compare(op, left, right):
    """ This function will print log everytime the assert fails"""
    log.error('Comparing Foo instances:    vals: %s != %s \n' % (left, right))
    return ["Comparing Foo instances:", " vals: %s != %s" % (left, right)]

def pytest_configure(config):
    """ Create a log file if log_file is not mentioned in *.ini file"""
    if not config.option.log_file:
        timestamp = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        config.option.log_file = 'log.' + timestamp
```

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = CRITICAL
log_cli_format = %(message)s
log_file_level = DEBUG
log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_file_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

test_my_code.py

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_my_code():
    ****test code
```

Comment: Beware that live logging is not the same as the `--result-log`. The former only persists the logs emitted by your code, the latter writes a copy of the complete test run output to file.

Answer (score 7):

#### Note

`--result-log` argument is deprecated and scheduled for removal in version 6.0 (see [Deprecations and Removals: Result log](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#result-log-result-log)). The possible replacement implementation is discussed in [issue #4488](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4488), so watch out for the next major version bump - the code below will stop working with `pytest==6.0`.

#### Answer

You can modify the `resultlog` in the [`pytest_configure`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) hookimpl. Example: put the code below in the `conftest.py` file in your project root dir:

```
import datetime


def pytest_configure(config):
    if not config.option.resultlog:
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        config.option.resultlog = 'log.' + timestamp
```

Now if `--result-log` is *not* passed explicitly (so you have to remove `addopts = --resultlog=log.txt` from your `pytest.ini`), `pytest` will create a log file ending with a timestamp. Passing `--result-log` with a log file name will override this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can have different pytest run logs by naming the log file the time when test execution starts.

```
pytest tests --log-file $(date '+%F_%H:%M:%S')
```

This will create a log file for each test run. And the name of the test run would be the timestamp.

`$(date '+%F_%H:%M:%S')` is the bash command to get current timestamp in `DATE_Hr:Min:Sec` format.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @SilentGuy's helpful solution, as answered in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76275752/5825523), you can add to the filename both username and timestamp via:

```bash
pytest . -vv | tee ./logs/$(whoami)_"$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)".log
```

where

- `.` runs all tests in `test/`
- `-vv` returns very verbose results
- `whoami` resolves to your username on linux/windows
- the date section produces YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS