# How to store logs in a separate file for each test in pytest

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I have the following code in `conftest.py`. It stores results from all tests to the same file.
I want to store logs in a results directory with the filename as `results/test1_<timestamp>.log`, `results/test2_<timestamp>.log` instead.

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    """ Create a log file if log_file is not mentioned in *.ini file"""
    if not config.option.log_file:
        timestamp = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        config.option.log_file = 'log.' + timestamp
```

The original link of above code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255889/14303498.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the logging path per test using `set_log_path` (though note that the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html#live-logs) considers it experimental):

*conftest.py*

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    logging_plugin = item.config.pluginmanager.get_plugin("logging-plugin")
    timestamp = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    logging_plugin.set_log_path(os.path.join('results', f'{item.name}_{timestamp}.log'))
```

Of course, you have to set the correct root path (I just put "results" there).
This will create a new log file for each test, with the name configured accordingly.

You can also use other properties of the item to compose the filename. If you want the test class name in the path, as mentioned in the comment, you can do something like:

```py
...
    path = 'results'
    if item.cls is not None:
        path = os.path.join(path, item.cls.__name__)
    logging_plugin.set_log_path(os.path.join(path, f'{item.name}_{timestamp}.log'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It gave me good start and it worked as it is. However I wanted to change the results directory to be results/$clsname

Comment: as following.```result_dir = os.path.join('results', str(item.cls))
    logging_plugin.set_log_path(os.path.join(result_dir, f'{item.name}_{timestamp}.log'))```  gets syntax error: E       OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\tests\\functional\\results\\<class 'Test_xx.Test_xx'>"

Comment: I added this to the answer, please check if this is what you need.

Comment: I used same method but its creating empty log files for me. any idea why?
I also added 'caplog.set_level(logging.INFO)' to the test function but it did not help.
The logs are still printed to screen.(when running pytest)