# PyTest - Logfile Replaced if Filename Mentioned in pytest.ini

Tags: python, logging, pytest, logfile, python-logging

I am writing set of test files with a lot of test functions. I have to generate log file for each run. So I added the lines given below in `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
log_file = Logs/log_file.txt
log_file_level = INFO
log_file_format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
log_file_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

I am expecting each log file during my each test run. But the file replaces old `log_file.txt` with new one  during each run. Is there anyway to create new log file with date and time as filename during each run?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `datetime.strftime()` function from the datetime module to generate the file name.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime('logfile_%YYYY-%MM-%DDT%HH:%mm:ss.txt')
```

The command generates a string with `logfile` as prefix followed by the datetime and then the file format.
This can be used to generate separate files for each run

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to add it to `pytest.ini` file. It is a configuration file for pytest. We can't import a python package inside that file. Simply python code doesn't work directly inside a `pytest.ini` file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165844/how-to-create-new-log-file-for-each-run-of-tests-in-pytest

Comment: Please refer to the above if that helps you.

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [@nithin11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11981663/nithin11) 's answer and the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165844/how-to-create-new-log-file-for-each-run-of-tests-in-pytest) provided by him, I modified my conftest.py as follows:

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    """ Create a log file if log_file is not mentioned in *.ini file"""
    if not config.option.log_file:
        timestamp = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        config.option.log_file = 'Logs/log.' + timestamp + ".log"
```

Also I removed `log_file = Logs/log_file.txt` from `pytest.ini`. My new `pytest.ini` is given below:

```
[pytest]
log_file_level = INFO
log_file_format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
log_file_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```