# Collect pytest test cases with separate script

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm searching for a way  to collect all test cases from several pytest projects. I need that to be a separate python script, which:
-takes the project path / tests folder as an argument

- collects detected test items using default pytest process (so there's no name convention changes or something like that)
- works with collected items in some way. Specifically, I would prefer to work pyth test cases documentation (parse it and store in some file, e.g. csv/json.

I have problem with retieving test cases collection outside of conftest hooks. I think I need to use _pytest.Pytester or something like that, but I actually don't know where to start. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the command:

```
pytest --collect-only -q
```

It will collect all tests, without running them, and you can take that output and use it as needed. The result will be a list of tests, with the complete `pytest` path for running directly. (You can also use `--co -q` as a simplified version.) Here's an example of output when running that from one of my test suites:

```sh
pytest --co -q
boilerplates/boilerplate_test.py::MyTestClass::test_boilerplate
boilerplates/classic_obj_test.py::ObjTests::test_data_url_page
boilerplates/sb_fixture_test.py::ObjTests::test_data_url_page
boilerplates/samples/google_test.py::GoogleTests::test_google_dot_com
boilerplates/samples/sb_swag_test.py::MyTests::test_swag_labs_login
boilerplates/samples/swag_labs_test.py::MyTests::test_swag_labs_login
boilerplates/samples/test_page_objects.py::MyTests::test_page_objects
```

You can also specify which folder that you want to collect tests from. Any of the output rows will be directly runnable, so for example,

`pytest boilerplates/boilerplate_test.py::MyTestClass::test_boilerplate`

will run that exact test. Here are some other `pytest` arguments that may be useful:

```sh
collection:
  --collect-only, --co  only collect tests, don't execute them.
  --pyargs              try to interpret all arguments as python packages.
  --ignore=path         ignore path during collection (multi-allowed).
  --ignore-glob=path    ignore path pattern during collection (multi-allowed).
  --deselect=nodeid_prefix
                        deselect item (via node id prefix) during collection (multi-allowed).
  --confcutdir=dir      only load conftest.py's relative to specified dir.
  --noconftest          Don't load any conftest.py files.
  --keep-duplicates     Keep duplicate tests.
  --collect-in-virtualenv
                        Don't ignore tests in a local virtualenv directory
  --import-mode={prepend,append,importlib}
                        prepend/append to sys.path when importing test modules and conftest files,
                        default is to prepend.
```

Remember to add the `-q` or else the resulting rows won't be of a directly-runnable format.

Comment: Hi. I am familiar with pytest arguments and tried it already. But what I receive is console output - not actual python classes / python list of strings.

import pytest

pytest.main(["../tests/", "--collect-only", "--noconftest", "-q"]) - I can't save the result to any variable.

Comment: You can send the output of that to a file (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31796491) and then parse that for what you need. The classname is part of the strings generated from ``pytest --co -q``.

Comment: That feels smelling bad. I think I will use this solution if will not find other way.