# How to write the pytest session's result to a log file while implementing pytest from within python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, save, pytest

I am running pytest via  python script (not command line). I am trying to write pytest session outputs (test summary, tests collected etc.) to a seperate log file. I came across answers for writing the seperate log file when running pytest from command line [How to save pytest's results/logs to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793540/how-to-save-pytests-results-logs-to-a-file)
Here my console output and log file out put are not same.

#test_functions.py

```
import pytest
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@pytest.fixture
def input_value():
   input = 39
   return input
def test_divisible_by_3(input_value):
    LOGGER.info('Running the test 1')
    assert input_value % 3 == 0

def test_divisible_by_6(input_value):
    LOGGER.info('Running the test 2')
    assert input_value % 6 == 0
```

#script.py

```
import pytest
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

pytest.main(args= ["test_functions.py","--log-level=DEBUG","--log-file=py_test_report.log"])
```

Execution

```
python script.py
```

I can see that py_test_report.log gets created, but not pytest summary as that displayed in console

**console out put**

```
platform linux -- Python 3.7.12, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/pytest_examples
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: anyio-3.7.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                        

test_functions.py::test_divisible_by_3 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_functions:test_functions.py:13 Running the test 1
PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                             [ 50%]
test_functions.py::test_divisible_by_6 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_functions:test_functions.py:17 Running the test 2
FAILED                                                                                                                                                                                             [100%]

================================================================================================ FAILURES ================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________ test_divisible_by_6 ___________________________________________________________________________________________

input_value = 39

    def test_divisible_by_6(input_value):
        LOGGER.info('Running the test 2')
>       assert input_value % 6 == 0
E       assert (39 % 6) == 0

test_functions.py:18: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_functions:test_functions.py:17 Running the test 2
======================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================
FAILED test_functions.py::test_divisible_by_6 - assert (39 % 6) == 0
====================================================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.07s =======================================================================================
```

**output of log file**

```
INFO     test_functions:test_functions.py:13 Running the test 1
INFO     test_functions:test_functions.py:17 Running the test 2
```

I would like to have same out put in log file as displayed in console.