# How to capture "PASSED" and "FAILED" status for each test which is run for pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Basically I am creating a custom log file where after every test executes I need to write to log file whether it passed or failed.
I am aware of answers related to hooks, but I assume there should be some simpler way to capture this data.

Many Thanks in advance!

Working with pytest testing framework in Python.
I have created a custom log file and want to add PASS FAIL results in that log file as and when test case execution finishes for each test.

Comment: How are you running pytest? Please also show example pytest output vs what each line is supposed to generate in your log.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793540/how-to-save-pytests-results-logs-to-a-file

Comment: @h4z3 after each test executes in pytest we get to see the test result wheteher it is passed or failed on the screen, so I wanted to know if there is a way to capture it during test excecution. Iam running pytest from cmd.

Comment: Do you really want one log-file for each test-_case_ or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @julaine no will create a log file at the start and then will update the logs for each test in that same log file. I am able to write logs but I want a way to capture whether a test passed or failed, so that I can populate the log file with that information as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick

```
python your_test.py > your_test_output.log
```

Comment: the logfile is created during script execution, and I want to populate that new log file with the test result

Answer (score 0):

To write test results for each test-case which is executed (or skipped), use the `-v` (verbose) switch for pytest. It is one of many options to control the output of pytest, see here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html

`pytest -v` will produce output like this:

```
=========================== test session starts ============================
collecting ... collected 4 items

test_verbosity_example.py::test_ok PASSED                            [ 25%]
test_verbosity_example.py::test_words_fail FAILED                    [ 50%]
```

This will be colored if pytest detects stdout to be a terminal but work fine when piped to text files also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned I am not aware of the log file name since it is created during script execution, so I cannot provide a name to pipe it to..... I am creating the log file using python logger.

Comment: So you want pytest to use your logger for outputting? I am not sure that is possible, and I fail what problem you are trying to solve. If your test run creates a log-file, why do you care if it gets created by the shell or by the python-logging-library?

Comment: Thanks, I taught of creating a separate log file, because I wanted to add some  information related to each tests as the test progresses and I am able to use python logger to achieve this  and I am able to write to log file. Just I am not finding a way to determine programmatically if a test passed or failed during the execution.

Comment: @Abhilash Maybe this helps: you can prevent pytest from capturing your tests stdout-output. Then you can have your own outputs and pytests output in the same file (if that is what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: @Abhilash maybe the top two answers of this question can give you ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405063/how-can-i-see-normal-print-output-created-during-pytest-run?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a plugin. The [pytest-csv](https://github.com/nicoulaj/pytest-csv) can do that.

Install:

```bash
pip install pytest-csv
```

Run:

```bash
pytest --csv out.csv
```

Here is a sample out.csv:

```
id,module,name,file,doc,markers,status,message,duration
tests/test_my_functions.py::test1,tests.test_my_functions,test1,tests/test_my_functions.py,,,passed,,8.583301678299904e-05
tests/test_my_functions.py::test2,tests.test_my_functions,test2,tests/test_my_functions.py,,,failed,AssertionError: assert foo == 'bar',0.0006891670054756105
```

Answer (score 0):

Pytest has a builtin option for generating JUnit-style test report XML files. If that format is close to what you want, then maybe that is an option.

```bash
pytest --junit-xml=report.xml
```

If you use hooks you get full access to all the test results in a very useful way. You write a few functions with "magic" names in the special `conftest.py` file (in the directory where you run pytest) and pytest will execute them as hooks:

```py
LOG_FILE = None


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    global LOG_FILE
    LOG_FILE = open("some_file.txt", "w")


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    global LOG_FILE
    if LOG_FILE:
        LOG_FILE.close()
        LOG_FILE = None


def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
   LOG_FILE.write(f"{report.nodeied} {report.when} {report.otcome} {report.duration}\n")
```

See this page for all the attributes of the TestReport class: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.TestReport

Some useful ones:

- `nodeid`: The unique identifier of the test case. Looks like `some/dir/test_foo.py::test_bar` (or `some/dir/test_foo.py::test_bar[param1-param2]` for parametrized tests)
- `when`: This is either `"setup"`, `"call"`, or `"teardown"`. The `pytest_runtest_logreport` hook is run once for each "when", so three times for each test case. You might want to only look at the `"call"` one, or maybe merge the three together somehow.
- `outcome`: This is either `"passed"`, `"failed"`, or `"skipped"`.
- `longreprtext`: This is the complete error message (in case of a failed test). It is usually a multi-line string with a stack trace. I have found that the first line beginning with "E " is usually a good approximation of a one-line error.
- `duration`: This is a float of how many seconds the setup/call/teardown took.

Comment: In a similar way, is it possible to get the duration of each test using hooks? I tried to use the documentation but I could only calculate the time taken for passed tests but not for failed tests.

Comment: @Naveen: Sure! The `report` object in the example has a `.duration` attribute. This has a value regardless of test outcome (passed/failed/skipped). https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.TestReport.duration

Comment: I updated the example to also show how to use `.duration`.